# When is it true that $(R[t]/f(t))[u]/(g(u))\cong R[t,u]/(f(t),g(u))$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (with $1$), and let $f\in R[t].$ Let $S=R[t]/(f),$ and let $g\in S[u].$ Consider the following question:

> When is it true that $$S[u]/(g(u)) \cong R[t,u]/(f(t),g(u))?$$ In particular, do we have to make any more assumptions about $R,f,g$ in general?

If an answer follows from more general theorems then I might just accept a reference.

---

**Some motivation.** Part of the point is that this is a kind of "sanity check". If the above holds true then by symmetry we can legitimately write things like
$$\mathbb{C}[\varepsilon]\cong(\mathbb{R}[i])[\varepsilon]\cong\mathbb{R}[t,u]/(t^{2}+1,u^2)\cong(\mathbb{R}[\varepsilon])[i],$$
which seem intuitively "obvious" (after all, $(R[t])[u]\cong(R[u])[t]$ in general).

---

**A special case.**
Consider the case $R=\mathbb{R},$ $f(t)=t^{2}+1,$ $g(u)=u^{2}.$ In this case the left-hand side is just $\mathbb{C}[\varepsilon],$ where $\varepsilon^{2}=0.$ We can define a map $\varphi\colon \mathbb{R}[t,u]\to\mathbb{C}[\varepsilon]$ by $h(t,u)\mapsto h(i,\varepsilon),$ and this has kernel $(t^{2}+1,u^{2}),$ which gives the result in this case.

In more detail, we have
$$\varphi(h_{0}(t)+h_{1}(t)u+\cdots+h_{n}(t)u^{n})=h_{0}(i)+h_{1}(i)\varepsilon,$$
so $\varphi(h(t, u))=0$ precisely when $h_{0}(i)=h_{1}(i)=0.$ This in turn means precisely that
$$h(t,u) = (t^{2}+1)[H_{0}(t)+H_{1}(t)u]+H(t,u)u^2$$
for some $H_{0},H_{1}\in\mathbb{R}[t]$ and some $H\in\mathbb{R}[t,u],$ and the result follows.

This special case was made particularly easy (I think) because of the simplicity of $g$ and the fact that $\mathbb{R}[t]$ is a Euclidean domain (probably among other reasons). It's not clear to me how to proceed even in more complicated special cases (for the sake of argument, what if $R=\mathbb{R}[\varepsilon],$ $f(t)=t^5+t+1$ and $g(u)=u^2-1$?).

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: Yes, you can check that both sides have the same universal property: they're both universal wrt maps out of $R[t, u]$ on which $f(t)$ and $g(u)$ both vanish.